# Anaconda Error: Invalid Distribution -atplotlib When Updating/Installing Library with Pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I get this error when I try to update or install a library. I use Anaconda. I asked the chatGPT  for a solution. He did not give me the right answer

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Look in `c:\users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` to find a file called `-atplotlib`-something-something and rename it to `matplotlib`...

This is an indication of a single bit having flipped in storage or in memory, turning an `m` to a `-`.

```
>>> bin(ord('m'))
'0b1101101'
>>> bin(ord('-'))
'0b0101101'
>>>
```